# using variable in sed

Tags: bash, sed

Somehow the following code isnt working. The echo shows the right command, but doesnt do the replacement in the file.

file abcd.txt:

```
\overviewfalse
\part1false
\part2false
\part3false
\part4false
\part5false
\part6false
\part7false
```

Code:

```
function convert_to_true()
{
        sed -i 's/overviewfalse/overviewtrue/' abcd.txt
        for iterator in `seq 1 10`; do
                match=part${iterator}false
                replace=part${iterator}true
                command="sed -i 's/${match}/${replace}/' abcd.txt"
                echo $command
                $(command)
                done
}
```

Comment: corrected. was a typo.

Comment: `TeX` is a programming language; factor out the `false` into a single parameter that is passed to the other commands so that you have only one place to change `false` to `true`.

Comment: Here's an example of how to pass an argument from the command line, so that you don't need to edit your files in-place: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243854/possible-to-compile-a-tex-file-with-command-line-arguments-passed-to-the-tex-fil My `TeX` skills are too rusty to suggest how to parameterize `\overview` and `\part1` et al, but http://tex.stackexchange.com can help you out.

Comment: @chepner i am editing tex to txt ! The reason is that in .tex the above program will anyways wont work, because numericals are not allowed in variable names. I found out later, that the program wont run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple anti-patterns used, 1) Get rid of using shell commands in a variable, use a function or an array. But you don't need either of those for your requirement. 2) Single-quotes don't expand variables in any shell.

Just do the brace expansion logic instead of using non standard `seq` usage,

```
for iterator in {1..10}; do
    match="part${iterator}false"
    replace="part${iterator}true"
    sed -i "s/${match}/${replace}/" abcd.tex
done
```

Or use a function all for `sed` if at all you need a separate function for it

```
sed_replace_match() {
    (( "$#" >= 2 )) || { printf 'insufficient arguments\n' >&2; }
    sed -i  "s/${1}/${2}/" abcd.tex
}
```

and call the function with search and replace patterns i.e.

```
sed_replace_match "$match" "$replace"
```

---

Or if you just want to do it all in one shot, just use GNU sed and don't worry about the numbers, as they are retained across replacements as part of the captured group `\1` in the below example

```
sed -r 's/part([0-9]*)false/part\1true/g' abcd.tex
```

If the contents look fine, use the `-i` option for the in-place edit of the file. Or for any POSIX compliant `sed` just use

```
sed 's/part\([0-9]*\)false/part\1true/' file
```

Comment: thank you. your solution works. will get back after reading more.

Comment: I did not know that single quotes dont expand variables and this sentence helped me. After changing single quotes to double as your first solution states, the program works now.